# Postman: is there a way to export tests from Runner in console?

Tags: postman, newman

At some stage of our CI workflow we use Newman to run Postman tests, before pushing updates of our API. The problem is that when one of the team members adds new tests to the Postman collection we then need to export them manually in Runner to use with Newman. We would like to automate this step. Is there a tool or any way to export tests via for example console without running Postman and doing this manually?

Comment: Are you a cloud subscriber? If so you can use the [Postman API](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/cloud_api) to fetch the latest version of the collection

Comment: Thanks this works! Can you make your comment an answer and I will mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a cloud subscriber, you can use the [Postman API](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/cloud_api) to fetch the latest version of the collection.